# invalid internet address error in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I uploaded image to Firebase Storage then I get Image's Url to Firebase Storage created link for image. Then I saved image's url in Firestore Documents. I get ImageUrl from firestore If message have a image and when I want to display a message. Before it was work but not its giving error.

```
Expanded(
    flex: imageFlex,
    child: SizedBox(
    child: Image.network(message["ImageUrl"].toString())),
),
```

[image]

EDITED

firestore
[image]
controller.dart
[image]

messages_view.dart
[image]

Comment: There could be several reasons for it, maybe your Firebase storage is out of bandwidth usage, your firestore or storage rules has problems or there is some problem while uploading or fetching download link from firebase. Please share these information so we can help you out

Comment: @MuhammadHussain I used a random url in google images. I got the same error again. I think this issue is not about firebase.

Comment: Please share your Firestore document screenshot (without any personal data) and function that you're using to fetch the imageUrl

Comment: What do you get when you `print(message["ImageUrl"])`?

Comment: @MuhammadHussain I edited to post.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen `print(message["ImageUrl"])` is showing what I saved in message's document. Its working.

Comment: What exact value does it output though? Also: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/testfirebase-ce49c.appspot.com/o/news1.png?alt=media&token=4da8fdbb-2228-42b9-9d60-ea5b9088ae92` this url saved in a message's document. print display `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/testfirebase-ce49c.appspot.com/o/news1.png?alt=media&token=4da8fdbb-2228-42b9-9d60-ea5b9088ae92` when I write `print(message["imageUrl"])`. but I got error when I write `Image.network(imageUrl)`.

Comment: Both those URLs seem fine, and when I open them in my browser I get the image from Firebase Storage. Try showing the image in your Flutter code with that specific URL hard-coded (i.e. `Image.network("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/testfirebase-ce49c.appspot.com/o/news1.png?alt=media&token=4da8fdbb-2228-42b9-9d60-ea5b9088ae92")`). If that gives the same error messages, you can significantly simplify the minimal repro. At that point, it might be time to debug into the `Image` widget.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried it to. I got same issue.

Comment: there is a bug for this in 3.10.0 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126650

Comment: Good find @Agreensh. Do you feel like posting it as an answer? That way others are more likely to find it, and w can close other questions against this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this error with version 3.10.2; it is gone with version 3.10.3. There is a fix mentioned in the release notes under dart/52373. A thread about the issue mentions that it can be avoided by unchecking "All Exceptions" under "Breakpoints" in VS Code, but I did not try that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Flutter issue about this problem introduced in 3.10.0
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126650

Comment: And its still there in 3.10.2

Comment: if you look at the linked issue, it says it's fixed on the master branch, so yes... not yet scheduled for a stable release. follow this issue (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52487) to see when it might be in stable.